# Change SQL Connection String

Tags: vb.net

I'm pretty new to vb and trying to play a little with Microsoft SQL Server and VB.NET.

I built a Form that shows some data from the SQL-Server-Database. I have two SQL-Servers, one is the Test-System, the other a Live-System. First I grabbed the Data from the Test-System. Now I want to switch to the Live-Server. So I Changed the Connection-String to the live-System.

Strange thing:

If I run the the program, an empty form comes up. If I Change the Connection String back to the Test-System, all works perfectly fine.

Server, User and Password are 100% correct. The Servers are an exact copy of each other. Query and Connection in MS SQL Management Studio are working perfectly fine on both systems.

```
Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=Sever1\SRV;Database=DB1;User=User1;Pwd=Pwd1"}
Public SQLCmd As SqlCommand
Public SQLExecQ As SqlDataReader

Function RunQuery(Query As String) As SqlDataReader
 SQLCon.Open()
 SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
 Return SQLCmd.ExecuteReader()
End Function

    SQLExecQ = SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY col1 ASC")

    Do While SQLExecQ.Read()
      'Code
    Loop

    SQLExecQ.Close()
    SQLCon.Close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If everything you mentioned above is accurate; it is hard to see that this is a problem with your code.

Comment: ...well, except that those Connection, Command and Reader object really ought not be global vars.  The Command and Reader objects especially are query specific and not reusable.  Setting global object vars to new instances as that code does, will cause it to leak

Comment: The Code-Snippets are copied together. The First part (including the Function) belongs to a Class which i created. Basically what i does:
Hit the "Play Button" (Connection-String = Test-Server) --> all works --> Stop

Edit the Server in the Connection String (to Live-Server) --> "Play" Button --> query doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Are there any errors? I take it the connection opens successfully? Is there data in `table1` on your live server? Also you should look into `Using` for `SqlConnection` and `SQLCommand`.

Comment: No Errors, Connection opens successfully, yes. There is Data in the table. But the query doesnt seem to return anything

Comment: Do you have a named instance `SRV` on both systems?

Comment: Give it a try using `sa` credentials.

Comment: I had a simmilar issues in my project. Changing It to _Using_ and eliminating _DataReader_ solved my issues.

Comment: Thank you to all of you guys. After i implemented a correct Errorhandling, a invalid conversion comes up... fixed it and its working now.